# AccessJWT in React context and updating it in async fetch wrapper

Tags: reactjs, async-await, jwt, react-context

In my group React.js project, I am storing the AccessJWT in a context. I am using Fetch to make HTTP requests. I want to create a fetch wrapper function when I make HTTP requests. The fetch wrapper will sort of intercept the fetch calls by running a refresh token handler and then adding headers to the fetch call before actually executing the fetch call. This refresh token handler will update the accessJWT in the context. However, I have run into the issue of trying to use context in an async function.

I know a way around this is a to pass in the hooks as parameters, but then I would have to pass these hooks in every time I make a HTTP request. Is there a way around this?

Here is some code for my fetch wrapper for an example:

```
let customFetcher = async (url, config = {}) => {

    const { User, setUser, JWT, setJWT } = React.useContext(UserContext); 
    // problem here

    config["headers"] = {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${JWT}`,
    };

    console.log(config);

    let { response, data } = await originalRequest(url, config);

    if (response.statusText === "Unauthorized") {
        refreshres = await refreshToken();
        accessJWT = refreshres.json().accessJWT)
        setJWT(accessJWT)


        config["headers"] = {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessJWT}`,
        };

        console.log(config);

        let newResponse = await originalRequest(url, config);
        response = newResponse.response;
        data = newResponse.data;
    }

    return { response, data };
};
```

Should I just send accessJWT and refreshJWT in cookie?

P.S. My group wants to use fetch cause it is lightweight. I don't think I can convince them to switch to Axios which would probably be easier for intercepting HTTP requests.

Comment: Post the code as well

Comment: And yes it's much easier using Axios interceptors, it's so much workarounds with Fetch.